# Preposition with 'line' when quoting from a text (prose or poetry) with numbered lines?

Tags: prepositions, quotations

When referring to a line or lines in/from (?) a text with numbered lines, is it

1. "the idea expressed **in line 25** is such and such"; "**in line 25**, the word 'lisp' is a clear indication that…"

   or
2. "the idea expressed **on line 25** is such and such"; "**on line 25**, the word 'lisp' is a clear indication that…"

   ?

Comment: *The idea expressed in line 25* is the common way to describe it. Things are expressed *in writing*. They are also expressed *on pages*. "In paragraph 2 on page 34,..." is fine.

Comment: I had a look at both these questions before asking mine, but they were about lines of code and I wondered whether the same prepositions applied to lines of words in a text…

Comment: and also, I was wondering (edited question) whether quoting a line for an idea it expresses (interpreting words or phrases) or for a word or phrase it contains changed anything?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a different (and new) question. It renders answers incomprehensible. If another question occurs to you after the first has been answered, please post a new question.

Comment: @medica: OK, sorry! Won't do that again.